# Convert a String representing a matrix of numbers to a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, string, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need to convert a String representing a matrix of numbers to a 2D Array.

```
Input - "1 2 3\n4 5 6\n10 20 30"
output - 1 2 3
         4 5 6
         10 20 30
```

I tried out this code but i am not able to figure out how i can work with numbers with more than 1 digit. I know the code sucks but please bear with me as I am new to programming and learning as much as I can from my mistakes.

```
int rowCount = 1;
        int colCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixAsString.length(); i++) {
            if (matrixAsString.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                colCount++;
                if (Character.isISOControl(matrixAsString.charAt(i))) {
                    rowCount++;
                    colCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        this.rowCount = rowCount;
        this.colCount = colCount;

        int i = 0;

        this.matrix = new int[rowCount][colCount];

        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++) {
                while (i <= matrixAsString.length()) {
                    if (matrixAsString.charAt(i) != ' ' && !Character.isISOControl(matrixAsString.charAt(i))) {
                        this.matrix[row][col] = Character.getNumericValue(matrixAsString.charAt(i));
                        i++;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hint: First split the string by "\n" and then each part split by "\s+".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using Java 8 streams:

```java
String input = "1 2 3\n4 5 6\n10 20 30";

String[][] output = Arrays.stream(input.split("\n"))
  .map(entry -> entry.split(" ")).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

If you want this to be a primitive `int` array, then this will work:

```java
int[][] output =
  Arrays.stream(input.split("\n")).map(entry -> Arrays.stream(entry.split(" "))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new);
```

or if you can use a boxed primitive, then this will work:

```java
Integer[][] output =
  Arrays.stream(input.split("\n")).map(entry -> Arrays.stream(entry.split(" "))
    .map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(Integer[]::new)).toArray(Integer[][]::new);
```

To view and verify the results

```java
Arrays.stream(output).forEach(item -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item)));
```

printed result is

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `BufferedReader` class, which has a `readLine` method.

You'll need to iterate the string value twice, once to obtain a line count, and once again to populate the array.
That is unless you would settle with a `List`, which will expand as we add values.

Nevertheless, here is a method that will generate a 2-dimensional array, given a multi-line `String`.

```java
int[][] matrix(String string) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(string));
    int count = 0;
    String line;
    while (reader.readLine() != null)
        count++;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(string));
    int[][] matrix = new int[count][];
    String[] strings;
    int indexA = 0, indexB;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        strings = line.split(" ");
        matrix[indexA] = new int[strings.length];
        indexB = 0;
        for (String value : strings)
            matrix[indexA][indexB++] = Integer.parseInt(value);
        indexA++;
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Here is a test with the string you supplied.

```java
String string = "1 2 3\n4 5 6\n10 20 30";
for (int[] value : matrix(string))
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[10, 20, 30]
```

And finally, I created a method which can be used to print the matrix.
It will format the values; right-justified.

```java
String print(int[][] matrix) {
    int maximum = String.valueOf(matrix[0][0]).length();
    for (int[] values : matrix) {
        for (int value : values) {
            if (String.valueOf(value).length() > maximum)
                maximum = String.valueOf(value).length();
        }
    }
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    String newline = System.lineSeparator();
    int indexA = 0, indexB;
    for (int[] values : matrix) {
        if (indexA++ != 0)
            string.append(newline);
        indexB = 0;
        for (int value : values) {
            if (indexB++ != 0)
                string.append(' ');
            string.append(("%" + maximum + "d").formatted(value));
        }
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

Output

```
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
10 20 30
```